# if someone marks an email sent from 3rd party service (swiftpage) using our spf record as spam does it hurt our domain reputation?

Tags: spf

Currently we have our work website and email accounts hosted by Verizon. We have been using Swiftpage to send out our weekly marketing emails to our customers. It has come to my attention that the emails are being marked as spam because according to https://www.mail-tester.com "You are not allowed to use one of your sender email addresses" (no spf key) and this affects us negatively by a large margin of 7 points on their scale of 1 to 10.

I want to add the swiftpage server's ip address to our Verizon spf record to fix this. HOWEVER I am concerned that in the off chance someone marks an email from our campaign as spam it will negatively affect our domain. From what I can gather, even with the spf record added the email campaigns are still sent from the Swiftpage servers. However I don't want to risk having our work domain, IP, or email addresses blacklisted.

Will a message sent by swiftpage that is flagged as spam hurt our domain reputation if I add the swiftpage ip address to our spf record?

Comment: You should always add a mailing service to your SPF record, else the marketing mails will be failing the SPF check. This should not have any influence on what happens if users mark an email as spam, but will reduce the risk of the mails being marked as spam by the receiving mail servers.

Answer (score 0):

actually if you already sent/sending mails with swiftpage servers using your domain as a send from address (or even as reply-to address) then it means your domain reputation is already related since then doesn't matter if you have spf already or not. I would say in this situation adding correct spf record can have more positive effect on your domain reputation.
So a message sent by swiftpage that is flagged as spam can affect domain reputation doesn't matter if you have spf or not. And spf just can help reputation anyway. Otherwise you need consider using separate domain for your marketing emails.